# Accessing params sent by an Ajax POST request

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am writing an Ajax request that sends a JSON-formatted string in a POST request.  Here is the relevant code:

```
var params=jsonString;
request.onreadystatechange = functionXyz;
request.open("POST", url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
request.send(params);
```

My question is how do I access the content of the POST on the other side?  In a typical form submission the data is sent as an associative array, but in this case I am not sure how to access the data - what the label is.  Is it by calling `$_POST["params"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a label for the json string (which is just a string):

```
request.send("params=" + encodeURIComponent(params));
```

Then on the server:

```
$object = json_decode($_POST['params']);
```

If you just send a JSON string, you can extract it from the post body, but I think that's unnecessary.